# How to share JS and HTML between 2 cordova projects?

Tags: cordova

I have 2 cordova projects, both of which are very similar in some respects. Right now I find myself copying code between them, which is bad. I'd like to share the similarities. How can I do this?

Comment: you can load CSS/JS from server but it will increase app loading time.